# I can't find the Django directory

Tags: django

I installed Django on an Ubuntu server using the apt package manager, and having a very difficult time finding some of the files referenced in the tutorials, in large part because I just don't know where the default install location is.

Specifically, the second tutorial tells to to find the directory `django/contrib/admin` templates, but gives no indication where that relative path starts.

I have explored the `/usr/lib/python-django`, which is where I found the vital `django-admin.py` file.

Is the source even installed when installed using apt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the locate command to find the absolute path.

locate django/contrib/admin/templates

Comment: Thanks! that is certainly a useful command to know. I found it in /usr/share/pyshared

Comment: You should execute updatedb if disk changes are made recently.